# Ninject with ActionFilters and SignalR

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, action-filter, signalr-hub

I have a mvc3 based web service which uses Ninject to manage its action filters, which all works fine. However now I am having to implement a SignalR hub into the mix and ideally want to re-use the existing action filters on these new hubs if possible.

One of the most important filters is the CookieAuthentication filter, which basically checks that a given request contains the right authentication cookie, if the cookie is not present or valid it sets the filtercontext.result object to a custom UnauthorisedResult object. So in this example are you able to use this functionality as SignalR to my knowledge has no idea about action results so not sure if it would automatically cancel requests etc.

I have tried googling but cannot find much info on the topic, I assume you cannot intermingle them as both frameworks only share the underlying ASP framework not the MVC framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. ActionFilters are for MVC only and don't run when using SignalR. The only common ground (as you realize) is ASP.NET itself. That means you can write an HttpModule but not an action filter.

You can learn more about SignalR security here:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security

Comment: Ah just the man, I was in a rush so I should have mentioned I have already checked out the documentation for securing hubs etc, however it all seems to use the default ASP.NET Authorisation, which I was hoping to avoid and just have a way to check the cookie against the db for the requests, which the functionality already exists for within the framework im using, and it is all just based on HttpRequest objects. However the AuthoriseAttribute seems to work against a user, not a http request, so should I just be getting the `HttpContext.Current.Request` in there and ignoring the user object?

Comment: Nah, it uses the "host" authentication. In this case the host is ASP.NET and in ASP.NET you can hook an IHttpModule's AuthorizeRequest and set the IPrincipal on the context to be whatever you please.